# How to connect ipv6 address with ssh?

Tags: ssh, ipv6

My local network is simple.

```
sudo ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.52  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::e23f:49ff:fe57:4bd1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether    txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 934205  bytes 918638128 (876.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 557104  bytes 69517532 (66.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2773  bytes 4761793 (4.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2773  bytes 4761793 (4.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I want to my vps which own  ip6 address.
[image]

```
ssh -vv -6  2001:19f0:5401:1cda:5400:02ff:fe8c:056f%enp3s0
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "2001:19f0:5401:1cda:5400:02ff:fe8c:056f%enp3s0" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 2001:19f0:5401:1cda:5400:02ff:fe8c:056f%enp3s0: Name or service not known

sudo ip -6 addr add 2001:19f0:5401:1cda:5400:02ff:fe8c:056f/128 dev enp3s0
ssh -vv -6  2001:19f0:5401:1cda:5400:02ff:fe8c:056f%enp3s0
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "2001:19f0:5401:1cda:5400:02ff:fe8c:056f%enp3s0" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 2001:19f0:5401:1cda:5400:02ff:fe8c:056f%enp3s0: Name or service not known
```

Comment: you don't seems to have public IPV6 address, address starting with `fe80:` are local, if testing withing same network, try sshing to `fe80::e23f:49ff:fe57:4bd1`

Comment: Just a hint: censoring the IP out of the command is not of much help if it's still visible in the resulting debug output.

Comment: Delete and post again if you are concerned about your IP privacy, as it will forever remain in the [edit logs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/567179/revisions).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision

Answer (score 0):

short answer:

you must define you public IPV6.

long answer :

I assume your ISP give you an IP, let's suppose you have `2001:0db8:0001:0001::0/64` as public IP (in fact public IPV6 network).

now, try

```
sudo ip -6 addr add 2001:0db8:0001:0001::0022/128 dev enp3s0
```

on local host.
(replacing value and network interface)

Note that you won't be able to test it from "inside". (I was unable save at time when I had two internet providers). You might use online test ipv6 tools from internet.

you can validate your ipv6 connexion using

```
ping -I enp3s0 ipv6.google.com
```

Comment: You cannot assign any random IP address to your host. That doesn't enable it to talk to the public internet, you need the network to route packets to your address. The host should have a proper IPv6 connection provided by the ISP.